# Displaying the corresponding div which is linked to a nav element while updating the hash value

Tags: javascript, html, css

As part of my thesis I implement a website. It has a nav with elements and divs with content.

I try to use the hash values in the url to display the right content div, the other divs are hidden/ set to none.

The url updates when I click the nav element (like the default behavior), but it's not showing the right div, because it's not adding the active class like it should.

The active class only sets display to block, like the commented line above.

I really don't know how to structure this whole thing. I also thought about merging the two parts, but I don't know how it would be best.

```
const pathName = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");

// Linking nav element with div
// And displaying active
navLinks.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    const targetDiv = link.getAttribute("href").substring(1);
    divs.forEach((div) => {
      if (div.id === targetDiv || !pathName) {
       // div.style.display = "block";
        div.classList.add("active");
      } else if (div.id == pathName) {
        document.getElementById(pathName).classList.add("active");
      } else {
       // div.style.display = "none";
        div.classList.remove("active");
      }
    });
  });
});

console.log("Pathname: " + pathName);
if (!pathName || pathName == "") {
  // document.getElementById("Home").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("Home").classList.add("active");
} else {
  // document.getElementById(pathname).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(pathName).classList.add("active");
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I got the substring(1) from another stackoverflow post. I deleted it and added the replace like in the pathName variable. 
I also wrapped the if else statement in a window load event and deleted some stuff. Anything else I could do to improve it?

Comment: I didn't show the full code, so no need to be sorry. 
I prefer the first jsfiddle over the second becauseI think it's more understandable. But anyway I thank you for your time to show me the hashchange event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a comment from @Yogi helped me, this is my working code if anyone has the same issue:

```
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links a");
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div.articleDiv");

// Linking nav element with div
// And displaying active
navLinks.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const targetDiv = link.getAttribute("href").replace("#", "");
    divs.forEach((div) => {
      if (div.id === targetDiv) {
        div.classList.add("active");
      } else {
        div.classList.remove("active");
      }
    });
  });
});

const pathName = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");

window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  if (!pathName || pathName == "") {
    document.getElementById("Home").classList.add("active");
  } else {
    document.getElementById(pathName).classList.add("active");
  }
});
```